# Laravel Task Scheduling not providing output on Failure

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

When in Laravel version 8.5.0 a Scheduled Task fails it is not providing me with an output in the `onFailure` hook

```
->onFailure(function (Stringable $error) {
     \\ To something with output
}
```

Link to documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#task-hooks

This is my current set up.

`kernel.php`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Stringable;

$cronId = 33;
$cronUrls = $healthChecks->getHealthCheckUrls('cron');
$schedule->command(DoSomethingThatThrowsAnError::class)
->when(function () use ($crons, $cronId) {
    return $crons->isActive($cronId);
})
->before(function () {
    Log::info('cron "do something that throws an error" has started.');
})
->after(function () {
    Log::info('cron "do something that throws an error" has finished.');
})
->onFailure(function (Stringable $error) {
    Log::warning("cron 'do something that throws an error' has failed. Error: $error");
})
->pingBefore($cronUrls['start'])
->pingOnSuccess($cronUrls['success'])
->pingOnFailure($cronUrls['failure'])
->days([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
->at('17:00');
```

`DoSomethingThatThrowsAnError.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle;

class DoSomethingThatThrowsAnError extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'cron:do-something-that-throws-an-error';

    protected $description = 'banana';

    public function handle()
    {
        throw new \Exception("banana");
    }
}
```

**What I excepted to happen**

That the exception is logged in `laravel.log`, since (correct me if I am wrong) all application exceptions are logged there.
And that the exception would be logged in the `onFailure` hook, like `"cron 'do something that throws an error' has failed. Error: (error gibberish)"`

**What actually happened**

The exception is only logged in `laravel.log` in general. Furthermore, the `onFailure` hook is called, but the  `$error` parameter is **empty**.

**Why is this an issue**

I use multiple log files and in the current situation I have to match an exception in `laravel.log` with an `onFailure` log in another log file. Which is often rather annoying.

**The question**

How do I set/ get the exception as a parameter of the `onFailure` hook?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `throw new \Exception("banana");` with `$this->info('banana');` OR `$this->info($e->getMessage());` in the catch block.

```
public function handle()
{
    try {
        // your code 

        // send output on success
        $this->info('Success message');

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        
        // send output on failure
        $this->info($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```